# Use the definition of limit to prove that: $\lim_{x\to-1} (x^2-2x-1) = 2$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I have some question about this example:

> Use the definition of limit to prove that:

$$\lim_{x\to-1} (x^2-2x-1) = 2$$

*Proof*:  $\vert(x^2-2x-1) - 2\vert$ = $\vert x^2-2x-3 \vert$ = $\vert x-3 \vert$$\vert x+1 \vert$ $\lt$ $3\vert x+1 \vert$ whenever $\vert x-(-1) \vert \lt$ $1$ note that $\vert x-(-1) \vert = \vert x+1 \vert \lt 1$ then $0 \lt x \lt 2 $ and $ -3 \lt x-3 \lt -1$  then $\vert x-3 \vert \lt 3$ let $\epsilon \gt 0 $ be arbitrary and $\delta = \min(1,\epsilon/3)$. Then $\vert (x^2 - 2x -1) - 2 \vert \lt 3 \vert x+1 \vert \lt 3 * (\epsilon/3) = \epsilon$ whenever $0 \lt \vert x - (-1) \vert \lt \delta $

My question is that where do he get $3 \vert x+1 \vert$ and where he get $\delta = \min (1,\epsilon/3) $.

Comment: You may want to read other answers in [epsilon-delta tag](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epsilon-delta) to see how this device with $\min$ is used in many such examples.

Answer (score 1):

He chooses $\delta = \min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{3})$, because he can arbitrarily choose $0 < |x - (-1)| < \delta$ as $x$ gets closer to $-1$.

The reason behind this is that we want to show that for any $\epsilon$, if the distance of $x$ from $-1$ is set to some small number, then the distance of the function from the limit is smaller than that $\epsilon$.

He shows the work above that $|x - 3| < 3$, so then $|x - 3||x + 1| < 3|x + 1|$. From there he chooses the minimum for $\delta$ so that the expression $3|x + 1|$ reduces to just $\epsilon$. You can do that because you can choose numbers as close to $-1$ as you want for $x$, so there's nothing wrong with setting $\delta$ to $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ where $0 < |x - (-1)| < \delta$.

Comment: so I was doing my homework prove $\lim_{x\to 2}(x^2-2x+1) =1$, I got to $\vert x^2-2x \vert$ = $\vert x\vert$ $\vert x-2\vert$ $\lt \vert x-2 \vert$... is that right or should I do $\vert x \vert$ $\lt 2$ then it will be ..$\lt 2\vert x-2 \vert$

Comment: Alright so we choose $0 < |x - 2| < \delta$. We assume $\delta < 2$, then $0 < |x - 2| < 2$, then $x > 0$, because a negative value would make $|x - 2| > 2$. So $0 < x - 2 < 2$ and $2 < x < 4$. So, $|x||x - 2| < 4|x - 2|$. If we now choose $\delta < (2,\frac{\epsilon}{4})$, we have $|x||x - 2| < 4|x - 2| < 4\frac{\epsilon}{4} = \epsilon$.

Comment: so its $\vert x \vert$ $\lt 4$ and it become 4$\vert x-2 \vert$

Comment: Yeah, if $2 < x < 4$, then $|x| < 4$.

Comment: ok got it, thank so much